# Installing Ipython throws error about setuptools

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, ipython, setuptools

I have installed `pip` and `setuptools` installed on my Mac with `pip`. While I am installing `Ipython` with commands: `sudo install ipython`,Errors following:[Link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15413863/). I have tried these commands: `sudo -H pip install ipython --ignore-installed setuptools-1.1.6`
,it also came out errors: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools-1.1.6 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for setuptools-1.1.6`.
I have googled similar problems,but haven't solved it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `virtualenv`. You can install it and then inside the project folder run `virtualenv .`. This will create a few new folders. Now you can run `./bin/pip install ipython` which will install `ipython` only on that folder. Can you do that and let us know if it worked? You can run all python apps using `./bin/python app.py` or by adding `#!bin/python`.

Comment: I made a new folder with commands:`virtualenv virtualenv`,and installed `ipython` successfully.And it works now!It's something about dependency that cause errors?Thx anyway.

Comment: Most likely yes. `virtualenv` takes care of all this by creating a new folder with a new copy of `python` and `pip` for every project. I recommend you try using it in all projects that require an external library. You don't need `root`/`sudo` and you don't install new things in your system that you may only need once.